# How to draw an outline around a block using Fabric api mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

How to draw an outline for a block using its coordinates? if its even possible using this code
In minecraft java fabric 1.20.1

```java
package net.kaupenjoe.tutorialmod;

import net.fabricmc.api.ClientModInitializer;
import net.fabricmc.api.EnvType;
import net.fabricmc.api.Environment;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.event.lifecycle.v1.ClientTickEvents;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.keybinding.v1.KeyBindingHelper;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient;
import net.minecraft.client.network.ClientPlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.client.option.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.text.Text;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.math.ChunkPos;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Environment(EnvType.CLIENT)
public class TutorialModClient implements ClientModInitializer {

    private static KeyBinding keyBinding;
    private static List<Block> blocksToCheck = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        blocksToCheck.add(Blocks.DIAMOND_ORE);
        blocksToCheck.add(Blocks.DEEPSLATE_DIAMOND_ORE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeClient() {
        keyBinding = KeyBindingHelper.registerKeyBinding(new KeyBinding(
                "xray i guess",
                GLFW.GLFW_KEY_P,
                "key.categories.misc"
        ));

        ClientTickEvents.START_CLIENT_TICK.register(client -> {
            if (keyBinding.isPressed()) {
                listCertainBlocks();
            }
        });
    }

    private void listCertainBlocks() {
        MinecraftClient minecraft = MinecraftClient.getInstance();
        ClientPlayerEntity player = minecraft.player;
        int playerChunkX = player.getBlockPos().getX() >> 4;
        int playerChunkZ = player.getBlockPos().getZ() >> 4;

        int chunkRadius = 2;
        int bottomY = 0;
        int topY = minecraft.world.getHeight();

        System.out.println("Certain Blocks within " + chunkRadius + " chunks around the player, from bedrock to the top:");

        for (int chunkX = playerChunkX - chunkRadius; chunkX <= playerChunkX + chunkRadius; chunkX++) {
            for (int chunkZ = playerChunkZ - chunkRadius; chunkZ <= playerChunkZ + chunkRadius; chunkZ++) {
                ChunkPos chunkPos = new ChunkPos(chunkX, chunkZ);

                for (int y = bottomY; y < topY; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                        for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++) {
                            BlockPos pos = new BlockPos(chunkPos.getStartX() + x, y, chunkPos.getStartZ() + z);
                            Block block = minecraft.world.getBlockState(pos).getBlock();

                            if (blocksToCheck.contains(block)) {
                                player.sendMessage(Text.of(" - " + block.getTranslationKey() + " at (" + pos.getX() + ", " + pos.getY() + ", " + pos.getZ() + ")"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code to find blocks in a certain radius, in this code example diamond ore and deepslate diamond ore

right now all it does is sends the blocks position to the chat

I tried all sort of methods, using chatGBT but nothing worked
Also tried googling but couldnt find anything that worked

Comment: [This](https://github.com/AdvancedXRay/XRay-Fabric) is a pre-existing fabric X-Ray mod and it might provide some insight into how to do what you are trying